# Large table to next page

Tags: tables

I have a very large table that extends to at least 2 pages, but the tables just continues down along the bottom of the paper.

How can I get it to extend to the next page?
And how can I get a bit more space above and below the text in one cell, so its more pleasing to look at?
And finally how can I fit the text to match the width of the cell and avoid getting the annoying "Underfull \hbox (badness 10000)"

The text in the cells feels very hard or almost impossible to work with, when dealing with such a huge table. Please just ignore the fact that the language is in danish.

The code:

```
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{ | p{4.88cm} | p{4.88cm} | p{4.88cm} |}
    \hline
    \textbf{Faglige mål} & \textbf{Dokumentation} & \textbf{Formål} \\ \hline
    Vælge og anvende fagligt relevante studiemetoder, studieteknikker og arbejdsformer & Fra billede af tavlen til ”jeg læser det bare på nettet el. I en bog” til noter i hånden & Løbende noter, notatteknikker og studieteknikker (SO-forløb – Final Countdown) \\ \hline
    Dokumentere viden om forskellige arbejds- og samarbejdsformer og planlægge og anvende disse hensigtsmæssigt i praktiske forløb & Undervisningsplan til undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2013
Gruppearbejde
 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Kombinere fagenes metoder og skabe sammenhæng i faglig viden inden for det enkelte fag og fagene imellem & Undervisningsplan til undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2013
Gruppearbejde
 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Udvikle kommunikative færdigheder, skriftligt og mundtligt, især ved formidling af videnskab og teknik. & Forklaring af evaluering fra undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2014 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Sætte sig faglige og personlige mål og evaluere kvaliteten af eget arbejde & Forklaring af evaluering fra undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2014 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Demonstrere praktisk indsigt i innovative processer og metoder til idégenerering & Kreativ ide udvikling – omvendt brainstorm – 17/11/2014 & Velfærdsteknologi i uddannelsessystemet \\ \hline
    Søge, vurdere og anvende kilder i de enkelte fag og i samspillet mellem fagene & Kildeliste fra rapport– 17/02/2014 - s. 26 – 27 & Final Countdown \\ \hline
    Producere viden om praktisk-teoretiske problemstillinger i samspillet mellem fag & PID controlleren – uddrag af rapport – 17/02/2013 – s. 12 – 14 & Final Countdown \\ \hline
    Redegøre for sammenhænge mellem den teknologiske udvikling og samfundsudviklingen i udvalgte eksempler & Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014 & SO-forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013 \\ \hline
    Udvælge, behandle og formidle centrale flerfaglige emner i en skriftlig opgavebesvarelse & Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014 & SO-forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for de tanker og teorier, der ligger bag erkendelse inden for teknologiske, naturvidenskabelige, samfundsvidenskabelige og humanistiske fagområder & - Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for, hvordan viden produceres og tilegnes inden for de forskellige fagområder & Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for forskellige videnskabelige metoders mulighed for at bidrage til en konkret problemløsning & Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Dokumentere viden om og anvende forskellige formidlings- og præsentationsformer. & Poster til forældremøde – 27/02/2014
- Mælkekarton – 27/02/2013
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Vælge og anvende skriftlig fremstillingsform til forskellige teksttyper & - Poster til forældremøde – 27/02/2014
- Mælkekarton – 27/02/2013
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

Comment: use the `longtable` (or `supertab` or `xtab` packages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a 2-page table. It is wider than the default `article` page width but I diod not change that as you gave no indication of your document setup (Please always supply full documents as below, not just fragments).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array,longtable}

\begin{document}

    \begin{longtable}{ |*{3}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash} p{4.88cm} |}}
    \hline
    \textbf{Faglige mål} & \textbf{Dokumentation} & \textbf{Formål} \\ \hline
    Vælge og anvende fagligt relevante studiemetoder, studieteknikker og arbejdsformer & Fra billede af tavlen til ”jeg læser det bare på nettet el. I en bog” til noter i hånden & Løbende noter, notatteknikker og studieteknikker (SO-forløb – Final Countdown) \\ \hline
    Dokumentere viden om forskellige arbejds- og samarbejdsformer og planlægge og anvende disse hensigtsmæssigt i praktiske forløb & Undervisningsplan til undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2013
Gruppearbejde
 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Kombinere fagenes metoder og skabe sammenhæng i faglig viden inden for det enkelte fag og fagene imellem & Undervisningsplan til undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2013
Gruppearbejde
 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Udvikle kommunikative færdigheder, skriftligt og mundtligt, især ved formidling af videnskab og teknik. & Forklaring af evaluering fra undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2014 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Sætte sig faglige og personlige mål og evaluere kvaliteten af eget arbejde & Forklaring af evaluering fra undervisning af 1.g'ere – 21/11/2014 & SO-forløb – undervisning af 1.g'ere – uge 47, 2014 \\ \hline
    Demonstrere praktisk indsigt i innovative processer og metoder til idégenerering & Kreativ ide udvikling – omvendt brainstorm – 17/11/2014 & Velfærdsteknologi i uddannelsessystemet \\ \hline
    Søge, vurdere og anvende kilder i de enkelte fag og i samspillet mellem fagene & Kildeliste fra rapport– 17/02/2014 - s. 26 – 27 & Final Countdown \\ \hline
    Producere viden om praktisk-teoretiske problemstillinger i samspillet mellem fag & PID controlleren – uddrag af rapport – 17/02/2013 – s. 12 – 14 & Final Countdown \\ \hline
    Redegøre for sammenhænge mellem den teknologiske udvikling og samfundsudviklingen i udvalgte eksempler & Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014 & SO-forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013 \\ \hline
    Udvælge, behandle og formidle centrale flerfaglige emner i en skriftlig opgavebesvarelse & Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014 & SO-forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for de tanker og teorier, der ligger bag erkendelse inden for teknologiske, naturvidenskabelige, samfundsvidenskabelige og humanistiske fagområder & - Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for, hvordan viden produceres og tilegnes inden for de forskellige fagområder & Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Redegøre for forskellige videnskabelige metoders mulighed for at bidrage til en konkret problemløsning & Speak til PowerPoint om den naturvidenskabelige metode – 27/02/2014
- Rolle til paneldebat – 19/09/2014
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Dokumentere viden om og anvende forskellige formidlings- og præsentationsformer. & Poster til forældremøde – 27/02/2014
- Mælkekarton – 27/02/2013
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ \hline
    Vælge og anvende skriftlig fremstillingsform til forskellige teksttyper & - Poster til forældremøde – 27/02/2014
- Mælkekarton – 27/02/2013
 & SO forløb – Menneske, teknik og natur – uge 38, 2013
SO forløb – Verden set og fortalt – uge 9, 2014
 \\ 
    \hline
    \end{longtable}

\end{document}
```